# Bash script to compare lines in 2 formatted files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two formatted files with lines with fields separeted by a delimitter ( in this case, '*' )

File1:

```
qwerty*asd*1111111*poiu*222222*mnb

nbcvxm*hjf*3333333*jhjd*444444*bvc

dhfkjs*bmb*5555555*vcxz*666666*ewr
```

File2:

```
cvcbfb*fgh*1111111*hgre*222222*hwg

qwerty*asd*2222222*poiu*333333*mnb

nbcvxm*hjf*4444444*jhjd*555555*bvc

tyterw*nbv*5555555*jhgf*666666*dsa

nbcvxm*hjf*7777777*jhjd*888888*bvc
```

I want to get lines that are in File1 but not in File2, but using as comparation criteria the union of 2 fields

For example, using as comparation criteria the union of field_3 and field_5

```
The line in File1   qwerty*asd*1111111*poiu*222222*mnb    exist in File2 as    cvcbfb*fgh*1111111*hgre*222222*hwg

The line in File1   dhfkjs*bmb*5555555*vcxz*666666*ewr    exist in File2 as    tyterw*nbv*5555555*jhgf*666666*dsa
```

So, the expected result in this case would be:

```
nbcvxm*hjf*3333333*jhjd*444444*bvc
```

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
$ head File{1,2}
==> File1 <==
qwerty*asd*1111111*poiu*222222*mnb
nbcvxm*hjf*3333333*jhjd*444444*bvc
dhfkjs*bmb*5555555*vcxz*666666*ewr

==> File2 <==
cvcbfb*fgh*1111111*hgre*222222*hwg
qwerty*asd*2222222*poiu*333333*mnb
nbcvxm*hjf*4444444*jhjd*555555*bvc
tyterw*nbv*5555555*jhgf*666666*dsa
nbcvxm*hjf*7777777*jhjd*888888*bvc
```

then using awk

```
$ awk -F '*' 'NR==FNR {keys[$3, $5]; next} !( ($3 SUBSEP $5) in keys)' File2 File1
nbcvxm*hjf*3333333*jhjd*444444*bvc
```

Comment: I think it can be simplified to `awk -F '*' '!seen[$3, $5]++ && NR!=FNR' File2 File1`

Comment: @Raffa that would also omit lines whose `$3,$5` occurs previously in File1 I think? But it may be what the OP wants ...

Comment: Yes, you’re right entries from File1 will still be added to the array and if `$3, $5` happened to be duplicated in multiple lines, then only the first occurrence will be printed … Good point and worth the extra step indeed.

Comment: Solution provided by steeldriver worked perfectly for the question I posted.

But Raffa, you just read my mind !!
What you said is exactly what I was looking for ( my mistake is that I forgot to say I also wanted to skip duplicates in File1 ).
So, your solution is perfect for me ( it gives the new lines without duplicates ).

Thanks steeldriver & Raffa